# How to match all the character after a word

Tags: java, regex

I have this sentence "I am a boy with French - Glukker Man". I want to match every character after French so that the regex highlights " - Glukker Man".  Currently I am using this: Currently I am doing:

```
(french[\s\S]*?)
```

But it's highlighting only "French".
This is the [regex test](https://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/74)

Please, how do I do it?

Comment: How about `(?<=french).*`

Comment: @khelwood It's capturing french. But I don't want it to capture french.

Comment: @Abdullq it's not capturing french, it's using it as a lookbehind. Just add parens around `.*` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind to match `french`, then select everything after it with `.*`:

```
(?<=french)(.*)
```

Then you can use it in your replacement:

```
<center>$1</center>
```

Alternatively, you could just match french and then only capture what comes after it.

```
french(.*)
```

In this case it looks like you're trying to surround your match with `<center></center>`, so for the second example to work, you'd have to capture `french` in its own group and put it back, or have it in your replacement:

```
Regex: (french)(.*)
Replacement: $1<center>$2</center>
```

Or

```
Regex: french(.*)
Replacement: french<center>$1</center>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is selecting this "french - Glukker Man".

Comment: @Abdullq - Sorry, I didn't see that you didn't want french in the capture. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(french[\s\S](.*))
```

use 2nd group to highlight it

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to do that in Java. Just split the string with the word that you want then use the second part of it.

```
String str = "I am a boy with French - Glukker Man";
String str2 = str.split("French")[1];
System.out.println(str2);
```

Output is: " - Glukker Man"